# How to sort nested aggregation field based on parent document field in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-nested

I have index of stores at various location. With each store I have a nested list of discount coupon.

Now I have query to get list of all unique coupons in a x km of radius sorted by the distance of the nearest applicable coupon on given location

Database :: Elasticsearch

Index Mapping ::

```
{
"mappings": {
    "car_stores": {
        "properties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            },
            "discount_coupons": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sample Doc ::

```
{
"_index": "stores",
"_type": "car_stores",
"_id": "1258c81d-b6f2-400f-a448-bd728f524b55",
"_score": 1.0,
"_source": {
    "location": {
        "lat": 36.053757,
        "lon": 139.525482
    },
    "discount_coupons": [
        {
            "name": "c1"
        },
        {
            "name": "c2"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Old Query to get unique discount coupon names in x km area for given location ::

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "geo_distance": {
                "distance": "100km",
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40,
                    "lon": -70
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "coupon": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "discount_coupons"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "name": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "discount_coupons.name",
                    "order": {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    },
                    "size": 200
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Updated Response ::

```
{
"took": 60,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 245328,
    "max_score": 0.0,
    "hits": []
},
"aggregations": {
    "coupon": {
        "doc_count": 657442,
        "name": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": -1,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 641189,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "local20210211",
                    "doc_count": 1611,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1611,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 160.61034409639765
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210117",
                    "doc_count": 1621,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1621,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 77.51459886447356
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20201220",
                    "doc_count": 1622,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1622,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 84.15734462544432
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "kisekae1",
                    "doc_count": 1626,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1626,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 88.23770888201268
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210206",
                    "doc_count": 1626,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1626,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 86.78376012847237
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210106",
                    "doc_count": 1628,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1628,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 384.12156408078397
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210113",
                    "doc_count": 1628,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1628,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 153.61681676703674
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20",
                    "doc_count": 1629,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1629,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 168.74132991524073
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210213",
                    "doc_count": 1630,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1630,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 155.8335679860034
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "local20210208",
                    "doc_count": 1632,
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "doc_count": 1632,
                        "distance_script": {
                            "value": 99.58790590445102
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now the above query will return first 200 discount coupon default sorted by count but I want to return coupons sorted on distance based to given location i.e. the coupon that is nearest applicable should come first.

Is there any way to sort nested aggregations based on a parent key or can I solve this use case using a different data model?

Update Query ::

```
{
"size": 0,
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
            {
                "geo_distance": {
                    "distance": "100km",
                    "location": {
                        "lat": 35.699104,
                        "lon": 139.825211
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "discount_coupons",
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "filter": {
                                "exists": {
                                    "field": "discount_coupons"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
"aggs": {
    "coupon": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "discount_coupons"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "name": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "discount_coupons.name",
                    "order": {
                        "back_to_base": "asc"
                    },
                    "size": 10
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "back_to_base": {
                        "reverse_nested": {},
                        "aggs": {
                            "distance_script": {
                                "min": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "source": "doc['location'].arcDistance(35.699104, 139.825211)"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question. You can always [order](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) a `terms` aggregation by the result of a numeric sub-aggregation. The trick here is to escape the nested context via a [`reverse_nested` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-reverse-nested-aggregation.html) and then [calculate the distance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-GeoPoints) from the pivot using a script:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_distance": {
          "distance": "100km",
          "location": {
            "lat": 40,
            "lon": -70
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "coupon": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "discount_coupons"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "discount_coupons.name",
            "order": {
              "back_to_base": "asc"
            },
            "size": 200
          },
          "aggs": {
            "back_to_base": {
              "reverse_nested": {},
              "aggs": {
                "distance_script": {
                  "min": {
                    "script": {
                      "source": "doc['location'].arcDistance(40, -70)"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I have read script are not recommended for realtime use case . If I say I have a traffic of 500 rps script will surely give high latency Also if I remember correctly script in es have a cap on running a defined number of times in an interval

Comment: You're right -- scripts *should* be avoided, if possible. On the other hand, I don't think there's any simpler numeric aggregation that can calculate the geo distance per-bucket and on-the-fly. You can try this agg in a sandbox and go from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help Is sandbox another tool or db can you me proper link or full name of tool

Comment: With "sandbox" I meant a sandboxed execution environment where you're in control. So first run it on a highly filtered subsection of all docs, then lower the filter, then try it under a small qps load, then a heavier etc. Not all scripts are created equal and this one might work just fine ;)

Comment: When I am using the above aggregation I am getting script score with aggregations the result returned is not getting sorted based on script score instead It is getting sorted based on term aggregation count. Do I have to sort in-memory based on script score

Comment: If the mapping is the same as in the question, the agg *should* be sorted by the geo distances from the top-level, non-nested `location`. If that's not the case, update the question w/ the response you're currently getting.

Comment: I have updated please check you can see distance score is coming still aggregation got sorted on based of count

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229450/discussion-between-aadi-and-joe-sorocin).

Comment: Hmm can you paste the query too?

Comment: It worked only had to pass "back_to_base>distance_script" in order field it was picking doc count as default